# The Data Loading Performance (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a big query in order to get data from 40 tables; the query contains (40 tables select) and each of select contains cases and multi join and conditions, also I have `UNION` after each of table select.

These selects from these tables exist in CTE then the final select from CTE.

The major matter is performance issue because i have a big number of data at each of table.

Could you provide me your major idea or tips in order to improve query performance?

Comment: This is a massively broad question. Why are you using CTE's for this, why union all of the data in one big query? are your indexes correct?

Comment: Break the problem into smaller parts. Examine each SELECT alone. Which ones are the problem queries?

Comment: Sure, The indexes is correct.
Also I use union in order to return the exact data from a lot of tables!

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates, or can you do UNION ALL instead? Are some of the selects similar to others?

Comment: This question can't be answered as it is now. There is no real data for any of us to work with. However, even if you did edit your question to include all the relevant data, It would probably be too long and cumbersome. Try braking down the query to smaller parts and see what can you improve in all these parts individually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at all 40 tables sizes and in the query plan see if SQL scans these tables or seeks. If it scans it, it is obviously timely I/O operation.
2. Check your statistics and Estimated vs Actual rows for your tables in the query plan. That might cause not effective plans and spills in TempDB.
3. Because there is a lot of data, it might be not enough memory and you have low Page Life Expectancy or even Swapping file activity.
4. Because of 40 tables, SQL Server might not come for the best possible execution plan. Then you have to look where it fails and fix it.

The best, would be to follow earlier advises and break your query into smaller portions if possible.

For instance, if you have something like:

```
;WITH CTE as (SELECT a FROM A UNION SELECT b FROM B)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN C on CTE.a = C.c
```

Try to replace it by this:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN C on A.a = C.c
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
INNER JOIN C on B.b = C.c
```

Or even do something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #t
FROM A INNER JOIN C on A.a = C.c
GO
INSERT INTO #t
SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN C on B.b = C.c
GO
SELECT * FROM #t;
```